# How to check the number of decimal places?

Tags: abap

If I have a value, could be a type P or a string, i.e. 12.345, I want to know if the decimal places is more than two.

I cannot seem to find a conclusive way of doing this in ABAP from my research. Does anyone know?

Comment: Can you guarantee in this context that the value will always be a number formatted like this?

Comment: Yes I think so,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the string will **always** be a number like this, then you could do this:

```
DATA(number_string) = '12.245'.
FIND FIRST OCCURRENCE OF '.' IN number_string MATCH OFFSET DATA(lv_position).
IF sy-subrc = 0.
  WRITE |There are { strlen( number_string ) - lv_position - 1 } decimal places|.
ELSE.
  WRITE |There are no decimal places|.
ENDIF.
```

Note that this will break if you don't have a properly formatted number. For example, if it is formatted in a locale that does not use the `.` as decimal separator, if it's a string with the number padded with spaces to the right or if there is for some reason more than one `.` in the string.